# mysql query using date of year

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a problem for querying records into mysql

explanation below
The user could pick a date to assign in variable fromdate and todate

example.

```
$fromdate = 2008/01/01
$todate = 2009/10/31
```

In above case, i have to loop and query with the ff:

```
SELECT * FROM table where date BETWEEN '2008/01/01' AND '2008/12/31';
```

second loop

```
SELECT * FROM table where date BETWEEN '2009/01/01' AND '2009/10/31';
```

if `$fromdate` and `$todate` is more than one year then I have to limit my query per year. But if less than one year then use `$fromdate` and `$todate` in the query.

Thanks in advance

Tirso

Comment: So what exactly is the question/problem? The formulation of the query or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to calculate the date.

```
$d1 = new DateTime($todate);
$d2 = new DateTime($fromdate);
$d2->modify("+1 year");
$min = min($d1, $d2);
$todate = $min->format('Y/m/d');
```

If you want to paginate the results, you will have to modify `$fromdate` on each page before doing the `$todate` calculation. For example, if you are on the second page, first load `$fromdate` into a `DateTime` object and add one year, if you are on the third page, add two years, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you mean but can you not use the mysql [Year](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function?

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(`yourdatefield`) = '2008'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(`yourdatefield`) BETWEEN '2008' AND '2009';
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the format of dates in MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD (not YYYY/MM/DD), so make sure you do that right. That might be why you are seeing wrong results.

`BETWEEN` works very well with (correctly formatted) dates. Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2008-05-12' AND '2009-04-23';
```